# Projected coordinate system that can be used for Nova Scotia, Canada for the linear units of feet

Tags: coordinate-system, canada

Right now I am using the projected coordinate system "ATS 1977 MTM 5 Nova Scotia" which is in the linear units of meters. I need to change the coordinate system for Nova Scotia, Canada to be something that will have the linear units of *feet*.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What program are you working in?

Comment: I am using Arc GIS. I have a DEM tif file for a region in Nova Scotia that has the projected coordinate system ATS 1977 MTM Zone 5. This projection has the linear units in meters, so the distance between two x and y points in the DEM is given in meters. I need to convert the entire DEM to feet. I was able to convert the elevation (z direction) into feet with raster calculator. I thought the only way to change the x and y to display in feet is using a projection system that is in feet. I can't find a projection system for Nova Scotia, Canada, in feet. How do I change the x and y to feet?